# Determination of a Function

Tags: equation-solving, functions

I have an expression: $5e^{13t} = F(e^{14t})$. I want to use Mathematica to determine $F$ on this function to be $F(q) = 5q^{13/14}$. How do I do this? Sorry if this seems trivial -- I can't quite formulate what I need to google it either.

Thanks!

Comment: `F[E^(14 t)] == 5 E^(13 t) /. (Solve[q == E^(14 t), t][[1]] /. C[1] -> 0)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually a tiny bit tricky as far as I'm aware, in that there's not a built-in syntax that "just does it"! Maybe someone's aware of a way Mathematica can easily solve for symbolic functions like this, but I'm not. (Mathematica has built-in syntax to solve for functions in the context of differential equations, but not in this sort of context, I don't think.)

Still, it won't be too difficult. We're going to use a combination of `Eliminate`, which eliminates variables from a set of equations, and `Solve`, which solves for an expression. We can write

```
ClearAll[f,q,t]

sol = Solve[Eliminate[{q == Exp[13 t], f[q] == 5 Exp[14 t]}, t], f[q]]
```

The answer is a list of lists-of-rules showing us that there are actually multiple solutions for `f[q]` here, one corresponding to each 13'th root of unity. (We also get a warning that this might not be everything.) We can use these as usual by writing `f[q] /. sol`, which will give us a list of replacements (one for each list-of-rules).

---

As a bonus, I wrote a function to do this automatically in the simple case where we have a function of a single variable equal to a function of another variable. I haven't really cleaned up the code, but the bulk of it is just to give the user options on how to use it!

In the normal case, the basic syntax is

```
SolveFunction[f[argexpr] == expr, f[q], oldvars]
(* or *)
SolveFunction[f[argexpr] == expr, f, oldvars]
```

Here, `oldvars` are the variables in `argexpr` that you want to get rid of, such as `t`.

We could write our request as

```
SolveFunction[f[Exp[13 t]] == 5 Exp[14 t], f[q], t]
```

First, here's a simple version, without all the option-handling bells and whistles, so you can see the core of the definition. This might be all you need.

```
SimpleSolveFunction[eq : f_[argexpr_] == expr_, f_[arg_], oldargs_] :=
  Solve[Eliminate[{arg == argexpr, f[arg] == expr}, oldargs], f[arg]]

SimpleSolveFunction[f[Exp[13 t]] == 5 Exp[14 t], f[q], t]
```

Here's how the more-controllable version works.

By default, I had it give a list of functions (and in the case where we specify `f` instead of `f[q]` in the arguments, anonymous functions), so that the result is actually usable! However, I also included an option that lets you set what you want the result type to be. Just specify the option `"ResultType"` as `"Functions" (* default *)`, `"Equations"`, `"Rules"`, `"ListOfEqautions"`, or `"Expressions"`.

Note that when we ask for `"Equations"`, I by-default change the solver form `Solve` to `Reduce`. The solver can also be specified independently by the option `"Solver"`.

You can also pass options to `Eliminate` by specifying a list of options as the value of the option `"EliminateOptions"`, and to the solver by `"SolverOptions"`. This can be useful when passing in assumptions.

Even the more-functional version is by no means polished. Certain capabilities that should be available via `Reduce`, `Solve`, and `Eliminate` aren't yet, we only allow functions of one argument, sometimes these methods fail, and error handling is nonexistent. Still, thought I'd just post this for fun!

```
Options[SolveFunction] = {"ArgumentName" -> None, 
   "ResultType" -> "Functions", "EliminateOptions" -> {}, 
   "SolverOptions" -> {}, "Solver" -> Automatic};

SolveFunction[eq_, f_[arg_], oldargs_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 SolveFunction[eq, f, oldargs, "ArgumentName" -> arg, opts]

SolveFunction[eq : f_[argexpr_] == expr_, f_Symbol, 
  oldargs : (_Symbol | {___Symbol}) : {}, OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[{q},
  If[OptionValue["ArgumentName"] =!= None, 
   q = OptionValue["ArgumentName"]];
  Switch[OptionValue["ResultType"],
    "Functions",
    (If[OptionValue["ArgumentName"] =!= None, 
        Construct[Function, q, #] &, 
        Construct[Function, # /. {q :> Construct[Slot, 1]}] &] /@ (f[
          q] /. #)) &,
    "Expressions", (f[q] /. #) &,
    "Rules" | "Equations", # &,
    "ListOfEquations", ((f[q] == #) & /@ (f[q] /. #)) &]@
   Switch[{OptionValue["ResultType"], OptionValue["Solver"]},
     {"Equations", Solve}, Or @@ ((f[q] == #) & /@ (f[q] /. #)) &,
     {Except["Equations"], Reduce}, {ToRules[#]} &,
     _, # &]@
    If[OptionValue["Solver"] === Automatic, 
      Switch[OptionValue["ResultType"], "Equations", Reduce, _, Solve],
      OptionValue["Solver"]][
     Eliminate[{f[q] == expr, q == argexpr}, oldargs, 
      Sequence @@ OptionValue["EliminateOptions"]],
     f[q], Sequence @@ OptionValue["SolverOptions"]]
  ]
```

I haven't fully tested every option combination yet, but here are some examples:

```
SolveFunction[f[Exp[13 t]] == 5 Exp[14 t], f[q], t, 
 "ResultType" -> "ListOfEquations"]

SolveFunction[f[Exp[13 t]] == 5 Exp[14 t], f[q], t, 
 "ResultType" -> "Equations"]

SolveFunction[f[Exp[13 t]] == 5 Exp[14 t], f[q], t, 
 "ResultType" -> "Rules", "Solver" -> Reduce]

SolveFunction[f[Log[x]] == 5 Exp[x], f[q], x, 
 "ResultType" -> "Expressions", 
 "SolverOptions" -> {Assumptions -> q > 0}]
```

Comment: Nice answer, thorimur! :)

Comment: @E.Chan-López Thank you! I appreciate it! :)